# Entity Framework Core and foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Entity Framework, and was trying to setup a small demo, for myself.

I have defined foreign key in my database

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firma] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Firma_BrancheKode]   
        FOREIGN KEY([BrancheKodeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BrancheKode]    ([BrancheKodeID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firma] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Firma_PostNummerBy]  
        FOREIGN KEY([PostNummerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PostNummerBy]   ([PostNummerID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Firma] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Firma_VirsomhedsType] 
        FOREIGN KEY([VirksomhedsTypeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[VirsomhedsType] ([VirksomhedsTypeID])
```

And they are showing in my database diagram:

[image]

When I go to the context file they appear there as well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Firma>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Firma");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Adresse)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.BrancheKodeId).HasColumnName("BrancheKodeID");

            entity.Property(e => e.Cvrnummer)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("CVRNummer");

            entity.Property(e => e.FjerdeSenesteKontrolDato).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.GeoLat)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Geo_Lat");

            entity.Property(e => e.GeoLng)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("Geo_Lng");

            entity.Property(e => e.Løbenummer)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Navn)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.NæstSenesteKontrolDato).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Pnr)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("PNr");

            entity.Property(e => e.PostNummerId).HasColumnName("PostNummerID");

            entity.Property(e => e.SenesteKontrolDato).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.TredjeSenesteKontrollDato).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Url)
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasColumnName("URL");

            entity.Property(e => e.VirksomhedsTypeId).HasColumnName("VirksomhedsTypeID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.BrancheKode)
                .WithMany(p => p.Firmas)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.BrancheKodeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Firma_BrancheKode");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.PostNummer)
                .WithMany(p => p.Firmas)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PostNummerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Firma_PostNummerBy");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.VirksomhedsType)
                .WithMany(p => p.Firmas)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.VirksomhedsTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Firma_VirsomhedsType");
        });
```

But my foreign key objects aren't mapped up.

Example: I get a random company

```
var firma = context.Firmas.FirstOrDefault();
```

But the objects om `firma` aren't mapped:

```
Console.WriteLine(firma.BrancheKode.Kode);
```

`firma.BrancheKode` is null

I can do the mapping manually:

```
var kode = context.BrancheKodes
                  .FirstOrDefault(e => e.BrancheKodeId == firma.BrancheKodeId);
```

And it works fine. But I was expecting EF Core to do the mapping.

Comment: You need to `Include` them, otherwise EF doesn't know if you want it or not. (And don't use lazy-loading, it's a bad idea).

Comment: Thank you @Dai, but I'm not sure I undestand what you mean by "Include them". The other entities are of course defined in the context-file. The other thing about doing the mapping manually was only to test if is was possible.

Comment: `.UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("BrancheKodes"));` does adding this help?

Comment: @fmansour add it where?

Comment: after this =>`.HasOne(d => d.BrancheKode)
                .WithMany(p => p.Firmas)`

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but it doesn't compile

Comment: Your model and mappings are fine. Your object **navigation** properties are null because you didn't ask EF to load (populate, fill) them. @Dai suggested using eager loading when querying entities, e.g. `context.Firmas.Include(e => e.BrancheKode)`. See [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) documentation topic.

Comment: @IvanStoev post an answer. That helped me